# Problem with vertical centering and Lines within tabular in tabularx environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, hline

I am new to latex and have some troubles with a table...
I want to vertically center column A and B to the table. I use a command to vertically center all cells. But when I include another tabular in the main table (tabularx environment) it centers the cell not to the middle of the tabular.
Additionally, the h-line within the tabular environment is crossing the border of the main table.

Hope my problem is understandable and that you can help me.
Thx in advance

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}
        {\textwidth}
        {
            |>{\hsize=.375\hsize}X|
            >{\hsize=.525\hsize}X|
            >{\hsize=2,1\hsize}X|
        } 
        
        \hline
        \textbf{Head A} & 
        \textbf{Head B} & 
        \begin{tabular}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.8\hsize}X}
            \textbf{Head C} &
            \textbf{Head D}\\
        \end{tabular} \\ 
        \hline
        should be vertical centered to tabular &
        this too &
        \begin{tabular}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.8\hsize}X}
            This is a long Text with multiple lines &
            This is vertical centered\\
            \hline
            another really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really looooong Text &
            AB \\
        \end{tabular} \\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
            colspec = {X[l] X[l] X[2,j,m]  X[1.5,l,m]},
            row{1}  = {font=\bfseries}
            }
Head A  & Head B    & Head C    &   Head D                      \\
\SetCell[r=2]{m} Should be vertical centered to tabular
        &   \SetCell[r=2]{m}    this too
                    & This is a long Text with multiple lines
                                &   This is vertical centered   \\
        &           & another really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really looooong Text
                                & AB                            \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot! That is way easier than my approach :)

Comment: @SamR, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will save time and  typing using a 3-row tabular table instead of nested tables.

You can then define a multi-row cell to vertically center the content of the first two columns.

Using the `nicematrix` package, the `\Block` command will do exactly that.

`\Block{2-1}{<content>}` will place the content in a 2 row x 1 column cell, centered vertically.

`hvlines` will draw all vertical and horizontal lines.

`cell-space-limits` expands the cells vertically.

The third column is twice as wide as the first and second columns. The latter has a fixed width. The internal computation is done by the package, just like `tabularx` does.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\noindent   \begin{NiceTabular}[width=\linewidth]{X[l] X[l] X[2,l] w{l}{0.2\linewidth}}[hvlines, cell-space-limits=4pt]
\textbf{Head A}                                     & \textbf{Head B}       & \textbf{Head C}                                   & \textbf{Head D}\\
\Block{2-1}{should be vertical centered to tabular} & \Block{2-1}{this too} & \Block{}{This is a long Text with multiple lines} & \Block{}{This is vertical centered}\\
                                                    &                       & \Block{}{another really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really looooong Text} & AB \\
\end{NiceTabular}       
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I tried it with the tabularray environment, and it solved my Problem. Still, I try to find some time to check out the nicematrix package